# get the page horizontal and put 3x3 images

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, zwpagelayout

First, I used following:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
....
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1c.png}}
\caption{Title for both}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2c.png}}
\caption{Title for both}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3c.png}}
\caption{Title for both}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

The above code creates three different pages, however I want them like a 3 x 3 matrix with **horizontal page**. How can I do that?

[image: What I want!]

Comment: The `subfigure` package is obsolete and has some incompatibilities, most notably with the `hyperref` and `caption` packages. It should be replaced with `subcaption` and its `subfigure` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put everything inside a single `sidewaysfigure` environment, i.e.

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1c.png}}
\caption{Title for all}
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2c.png}}
\caption{Title for all}
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3c.png}}
\caption{Title for all}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

it will work. Another possible solution involves the `pdflscape` package (using this package has the advantage that the page is rotated in the pdf viewer, so you don't have to rotate your neck). The code is presented below. The `caption` package is used only to adjust the space between the figures and the caption, through `\captionsetup` (you could use this as well if you decide to stick to `sidewaysfigure`). If the figure is inside a document, it may prove useful to use `afterpage` (remove % from the commented lines)

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt}
%\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
%\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot1c.png}}
\caption{Title for all}
\vskip3ex
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot2c.png}}
\caption{Title for all}
\vskip3ex
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3a.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3b.png}}
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figures/plot3c.png}}
\caption{Title for all}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
%}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If instead of "Figure 1", "Figure 2" anf "Figure 3" you want all the subfigures in the same figure, just remove the first two `\caption{...}` commands. Then the subfigures will be labeled fro (a) to (i)